# Expanding div using inner content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got the following div structure which I created using bootstrap. The html markup is as following.

```
<section class='content-wrapper order-summary-wrapper'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 order-summary-details">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <div>
                                <h4>Delbetalning Engångskostnad</h4>
                                <p>150kr/mån</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <h4>Abonnemang</h4>
                            <p>199kr/mån</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <div class='price-container-wrapper'>
                                <div class='price-container'>
                                    <h4>Månadskostnad</h4>
                                    <p>199kr</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class='clearfix'></div>
                                <div class='price-container price-container-padding'>
                                    <h4>Bindingstid</h4>
                                    <p>0 mån</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class='clearfix'></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                            <div class='price-container'>
                                <h4>Månadskostnad</h4>
                                <p>199kr</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='clearfix'></div>
                            <div class='price-container price-container-padding'>
                                <h4>Bindingstid</h4>
                                <p>0 mån</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <a href="#" class="learn-btn order-btn order-gray wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible;">Rensa</a>
                    <a href="#" class="learn-btn order-btn order-green wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible;">Beställ</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And I've styled it to look like in the following mockup.

[image: mockup]

Now what I've to do is when I click on each arrow icon the respective box should expand as below.

[image: mockup]

The height of each container is dependent on the content inside. I've tried making the container `position:absolute` and then using jQuery `slideDown`,`slideUp` methods. But this doesn't work as expected since when I make a container `position:absolute` the other neighboring containers stack on the left. How can I achive this effect using css + jquery. Or is it possible with CSS only?

will provide the current CSS of the containers if necessary.

following is the fiddle of the container. I've added the entire css since couldn't filter out the exact css needed for this bit of elements.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6z94gv0/)

Comment: give some example link to understand it

Comment: Perhaps create a bootply.com and share it here.

Comment: Provide the CSS or a Jsfiddle, and as a suggestion try to give your container a `height : auto ;`

Comment: I've added a fiddle with the codes and css!

Comment: your fiddle is not working, you could try something with: `height : 100%; max-height : 50px;` and onclick `max-height : 600px;`

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you can do it with bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

I apologize but I don't have time to realize the all think.

I can quickly show you a way it can be done, you will have to adapt it and make it better.

Try add this to your fiddle:
CSS:

```
.col-xs-3{
    border:2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:50px;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition:max-height 0.4s ease 0s;
}
/*
.col-xs-3:hover{
    max-height:400px;    
}
*/
```

JS: (this is vanilla js no-jquery)
-- make sure you select "no wrap - in < head > "-- top/left in fiddle

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(e){
    var m = document.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-3");
    for(var i=0; i<m.length; i++){
        m[i].isOpen = false;
        m[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
            if(this.isOpen){ this.style.maxHeight = "60px"; this.isOpen = false; }
            else{ this.style.maxHeight = "400px"; this.isOpen = true; }
        },false);
    };
},false);
```